# SAPUI5 Model Refresh Count and Average Time

Tags: html, model, refresh, sapui5

After a button click I synchronize my Application.

Now I need to find a solution to count those synchronisations and measure the average time used for those.

```
that.getView().getModel().refresh(true);
```

I am sorry the answer seemed unclear.

I have to count the syncs and Display it in a detailspage. And then I have to measure the average time the sync was working.

Comment: Your question seems really broad. Can you try to point out clearly what you are asking? **Average time:** Create timestamp, do stuff, create another timestamp, calculate diff, store diff (`jQuery.sap.storage`), calculate avg of all diffs. **Number of sync:** While syncing check if object was altered / differs from remote object. If true increment number of syncs.

Comment: I changed the topic a lil' bit. Yes, I have to count every sync that happened and display it in a detailpage while measuring the average time the sync needs.

Comment: Alright, thank you for the help with the timestamp, simple as that. I still don't know how to use the storage, google it though

Comment: The `jQuery.sap.storage` is just a very basic way of storing key-value-pairs in your browser. Your key could be `"sync_times"`, your value is an array of times. Since key and value have to be of type string. use `JSON.stringify` and `JSON.parse` to store/retreive your array.